# Application-defined or object-defined error with FormulaR1C1

Tags: vba, excel

I've got some code that isn't working, and have basically simplified it as much as possible for the sake of this post.  I'm trying to run this macro and get an error saying

> Application-defined or object-defined error

Am I missing something obvious?

```
Sub Test()
Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = _
"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1],R2C6:R4C7,2,FALSE),0))"
End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: `"=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], R2C6:R4C7, 2, FALSE)"`

Comment: What an absolute doughnut! I should have noticed this - thanks for helping though :)

Comment: @Jeeped Post it as answer. I came here to check and saw already is solutioned by you LoL xD

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - this is really a typographical error although I suspect it actually came from a copy & paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your VLOOKUP has an extra parameter hanging off the right side.

```
Sub Test()
    Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = _
      "=VLOOKUP(RC[-1], R2C6:R4C7, 2, FALSE)"
End Sub
```